# Array in JavaScript is undefined

Tags: javascript, undefined

I am very new to JavaScript but have good experience with C and java. For whatever reason my code below will not fill in the array with values other than undefined. I'm trying to simply fill an array with a random set of numbers for a blackjack game

```js
let randomSuite;
let randomNum
let count = 0;
var cards = new Array(56);
window.onload = function main(){
const suites = [
    "H",
    "D",
    "S",
    "C"
];

for(let i = 0 ; i < 56 ; i++){
    randomNum = (Math.random * 12) + 1;
    randomSuite = Math.random * 3;
    cards.push = randomNum;
    console.log(cards[i]);
    count++;
}
alert(cards[1]);
}
function hitFunc(){
    alert("works " + cards[0]);
}
```

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding : 0;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

.main{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color:black;
}

.img1{
    position: relative;
    z-index: -1;
    margin: 10px auto 20px;
    display: block;
    width: 75%;
    height: 75%;
}

.img2{
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    margin: 10px auto 20px;
    display: block;
    bottom: 200px;
    right: 400px;
    width: 7%;
    height: 7%;
}

.hitButton {
z-index: 1;
position: relative;
text-align: center;
left: 225px;
bottom: 550px;
}

.center {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 50%;
    color: aliceblue;
    object-position: center;
  }
```

Here's what I have. The alerts are used to show that the function is being completed. Any help is appreciated Please leave an explanation as well. This is my first post on stack overflow let me know if there's anyway to improve the quality of my post.

Comment: Rather than `cards.push = randomNum;` you need `cards.push(randomNum);`. You are reassigning the push function to a variable here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. `Math.random` is a function; use [`Math.random()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random)
2. Same for `push`, use [`cards.push(randomNum)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)
3. You were defining an array with 56 spots `new array(56)` but since you're using `push` you'll need to create an empty array so you're pussing to the desired index. Otherwise, instead of `push`, just set it on the index: `cards[i] = randomNum`
4. No need for the `count` variable since the loop iterator (`i`) has the same value

```js
let randomSuite;
let randomNum
var cards = new Array();

window.onload = function main(){
    const suites = [
        "H",
        "D",
        "S",
        "C"
    ];

    for(let i = 0 ; i < 56 ; i++){
        randomNum = (Math.random() * 12) + 1;
        randomSuite = Math.random() * 3;
        cards.push(randomNum);
    }
    console.log(cards)
}
```

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding : 0;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

.main{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color:black;
}

.img1{
    position: relative;
    z-index: -1;
    margin: 10px auto 20px;
    display: block;
    width: 75%;
    height: 75%;
}

.img2{
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    margin: 10px auto 20px;
    display: block;
    bottom: 200px;
    right: 400px;
    width: 7%;
    height: 7%;
}

.hitButton {
z-index: 1;
position: relative;
text-align: center;
left: 225px;
bottom: 550px;
}

.center {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 50%;
    color: aliceblue;
    object-position: center;
  }
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked I stared at this for a little too long.

Answer (score 0):

#### Call functions with parenthesis

`Math.random()` and `push()` are functions not variables therefore you need to call them using `()`.

#### `push()` will append to the array

`push()` will append a value to the array. You already initialize an array with 10 values. Pushing new values will increase the array size but not add values in the first 10 spots.

```js
const array = new Array(10);

for(let i = 0; i < 10; i++){
  array.push(i);
}
console.log(array);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

#### Solution

You should instead use `array[i] = value;` to set a value on a given position.

```js
const array = new Array(10);

for(let i = 0; i < 10; i++){
  array[i] = i;
}
console.log(array);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

If you want to have a more functional way of doing this as is typical for JavaScript you could use [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```js
const array = [...new Array(10)].map((_, index) => index);
console.log(array);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```